# How to override an existing interface implementation in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I'd like to create a custom `ILayoutManager` in my module for Orchard CMS:

```
CustomLayoutManager : ILayoutManager
```

And I want to override the exiting `ILayoutManager` (in `Orchard.Layouts` module) implementation.

But I don't know which Orchard API I can use to do it, how can I enforce Orchard to use my implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.Autoroute.Services.AutorouteService")]
public class SbSiteGovernModule : Module {
        builder.RegisterType<MyAutorouteService>().As<IAutorouteService>();
}
```